# How can I add armadillo vectors using MPI Allreduce?

Tags: c++, mpi, armadillo

I want to perform `MPI_Allreduce operation` on Armadllio vectors but I am getting 0 output. Essentially, I each processor has arma vector v. Using MPI_Allreduce, I want to add all the vectors in w. I am not sure if I have to add some synchronization. Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include<armadillo>  

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

vec v(2,fill::randu);

vec w(2,fill::zeros);

MPI_Allreduce(&w, &v, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(world_rank==0)
cout<<"w: "<<w<<endl;
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

My output:

```
 w:     0
      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with your `MPI_Allreduce` call. Firstly, you have 2 `double`s in your `vec`s, so the count should be 2. Secondly, you have switched the send and receive buffers.

> int MPI_Allreduce ( void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
>                      MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm )

So your command should be:

```
MPI_Allreduce(&v, &w, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Assuming the data held in the armadillo vectors are stored contiguously starting as the first byte of the class/struct itself, this should work fine.

**EDIT**: I looked a little more thoroughly at the armadillo documentation. There is a function `memptr()` which returns a pointer to the data itself. This is what you should be using for `MPI_Allreduce()` instead of `&vector`. Therefore, your actual function call should be:

```
MPI_Allreduce(v.memptr(), w.memptr(), 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```